# 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'author Issue with adding a cooldown on event

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to add a cooldown to a `on_raw_reaction_add` event in discord.py. I'm trying to do this by using cooldown mapping. The result should be to limit how many times this message

```
embed.description = f"It looks like you're joining us on a newly registered account. Verification requires accounts to be atleast a day old so please stick around and try again at {test_time.time().strftime(format)}."
```

is sent to a user if they don't meet the account age upon adding a reaction, which should be one reaction before the cooldown kicks in.

The error I get is  `'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'author` not sure why this is happening.

Here is the full code I'm working with:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):  # Will be dispatched every time a user adds a reaction to a message the bot can se
    general = self.bot.get_channel(701547632354525249)
    introductions = self.bot.get_channel(705068046267580566)
    botroom = self.bot.get_channel(706610280032894996)
    if not payload.guild_id:
        # In this case, the reaction was added in a DM channel with the bot
        return 
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    author = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(payload)
    retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    seconds = bucket.update_rate_limit()
    seconds = round(seconds, 2)
    hours, remainder = divmod(int(seconds), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    if retry_after:
        verification_error = f"You can do that again in **{minutes}m {seconds}s**."
        embed = discord.Embed(title="You have already verified.", description=verification_error, colour=discord.Colour(0xff8100))
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        pass
    
    if payload.message_id != 743841858727444550:
        return
    else:
        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)  # You need the guild to get the member who reacted
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)  # Now you have the key part, the member who should receive the role
    
        if payload.emoji.id != 743077610115956816:
            reaction = payload.emoji.id
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Members")
            newbies = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Newbies")
            restricted_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Restricted")
            role = discord.Object(743840972068356116)  # Pass the role's ID here
        else:
            return
        
        if restricted_role in member.roles:
            return
    
        
        if member.created_at + dt.timedelta(days=30) <= dt.datetime.today():
            await member.add_roles(role, reason='New member verified')  # Finally add the role to the member
            await member.add_roles(newbies, reason='New member verified')  # Finally add the role to the member
            welcome = f'Welcome {member.mention}! feel free to get started with adding some <#706648361196978177>'
            intros = f'Hey {member.mention}! now that you\'re a member of our group, maybe you\'d like to tell us a bit about yourself. Tell us an interesting fact about yourself and so on... As always keep it sensible and fun.'
            await general.send(welcome)
            sent = await introductions.send(intros)
            await asyncio.sleep(900)
            await sent.delete()
        else:
            format = '%I:%M%p'
            member1 = member.created_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")
            dt3 =  dt.datetime.strptime(member1, format)
            test_time = dt3 + dt.timedelta(minutes = 1500)
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color(0x7289DA))
            embed.title = f"Hey there {member.display_name}!"
            embed.description = f"It looks like you're joining us on a newly registered account. Verification requires accounts to be atleast a day old so please stick around and try again at {test_time.time().strftime(format)}."
            await member.send(embed=embed)
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Under your @client.command statement just add
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
This example will give a single user a cool down of 30 seconds for 1 use. You can configure BuckType to channel and server as well.

Comment: I found that you cannot use `commands.cooldown` with events but only commands. I would need to use cooldown mapping method and even that I'm finding difficult with unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was unable to help you.